# Weak star null sequence of norm one vectors in infinite dimensional Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $(X, \|.\|)$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space. I would like to ask whether we could construct a sequence $\{x_n^*\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X^*$ (dual space of $X$) such that:

- $\|x_n^*\|_{X^*}=1$;
- $\{x_n\}$ is weakly convergent to $0$.

Example. Let $H=\ell_2$ be the real Hilbert space. Then $H^*=\ell_2$ and we can choose $\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset H^*$ as
$$
x^1=(1,0, \ldots, 0)
$$
$$
x^2=(0,1, \ldots, 0)
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
x^n=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots, 0)
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
Then $x^n\overset{w^*}{\rightarrow} 0$ and $\|x^n\|_{H^*}=1$.

Comment: What you can see easily in general is that the weak$^*$ closure of $S_{X^*} = \{x^* \in X^* \mid \|x^*\| = 1\}$ contains $0$, as weak$^*$-open sets are so "large" that they will allways contain a line. But I doubt that there will allways be a sequence ...

Comment: @martini: How can we continue?

Comment: You know that your claim is true? Is there allways a sequence? As I wrote, I doubt that sequences are sufficient ...

Comment: The question seems poorly expressed to me; are there typos in the phrase "$\{ x_n\}$ is weakly convergent to $0$"? What is $\{ x_n\}$ in relation to $\{ x_n^\ast\}$, and why do you change from weak convergence to weak$^\ast$ convergence? Anyway, have you heard of the Josefson-Nissenzweig theorem? It might be of interest, depending on what you mean by your question.

Comment: Looking now at the title of the question, I think I know what the OP wants to ask; the Josefson-Nissenzweig theorem provides an answer in the affirmative: every infinite dimensional dual Banach space contains a weak$^\ast$-null sequence of norm-1 vectors.

Comment: @Philip Brooker: Here $H$ is a Hilbert space ($H=H^*$).

Comment: @Philip Brooker: Where we can find the solution of my question.

Comment: @blindman: okay, but earlier you are talking about a Banach space $X$... Anyway, for the answer to your question see Chapter XII Joe Diestel's book *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*; the entire (short) chapter is devoted to the proof of the Josefson-Nissenzweig theorem. I hope this helps :-) .

Comment: @Philip Brooker: Thank your for your introduction. Could you send me this book.